# foreign key to auto update

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm relatively new to relational databases and I'm not sure if what I want to do is possible. Could some one please tell me how to do this.

I have this named table1 where id is primary key

```
Id          userName 
1                 A
2                 C
3                 F
```

and I have this table2 which is now empty, Id is a foreign key  that REFERENCEd on table1 (Id)

```
Id              amount
```

I want to set up my database so that  the values in table1  id column  are equal to the the values in tables2 id column and  anytime an entry is added in table1 id column ,the same value is added table2 id  column .

That change will also be reflected in table_1

Comment: It sounds like your Table_1 and Table_2 have one-to-one relationship.  If this is the case, what is your reason to have two separate tables?

Comment: Table1 is the parent Table2 is the child. You dont have to have a child row just because you have a parent row, but if you do create a child row, it has to have a parent row with the id you use in the child

Comment: @PM77-1 in the database I'm creating I want to have two tables which where one on can hold the user info and the second on to hold  the amount the user might have earned

Comment: @kimomokioko . . . I think the question is why these need to be different tables.  It sounds like you just need more columns in one table.